# How to generate Allure xml when running project as TestNG Suite in eclipse?

Tags: java, maven, testng, allure

I googled about this question. The results I found suggested that I need to run a maven/ant build to generate the xml.

My project is an Maven & TestNG project. But while debugging we use the option 'Run as TestNG Suite' in eclipse.

I have added the following code to my testng.xml.

```
<listeners>
    <listener class-name="ru.yandex.qatools.allure.testng.AllureTestListener" />
</listeners>
```

This generates the UUID-testsuite.xml in project\target\site\allure-maven-plugin\data directory, but the report just contains the suite title and no other data is displayed.

I understand that in order to make @Step and @Attachment annotations work we need to correctly enable AspectJ in configuration. I am not sure how to do this in testng.xml file.

Please let me know, if I am missing something here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming, you have @Step and @Attachment methods are define in your test code, you just need to add aspectjweaver dependency in pom.xml file. Refer this Allure github [wiki page](https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-core/wiki/TestNG)

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.14</version>
            <configuration>
                <testFailureIgnore>false</testFailureIgnore>
                <argLine>
                    -javaagent:${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/${aspectj.version}/aspectjweaver-${aspectj.version}.jar
                </argLine>
                <!--only for 1.3.* TestNG adapters. Since 1.4.0.RC4, the listener adds via ServiceLoader-->
                <properties>
                    <property>
                        <name>listener</name>
                        <value>ru.yandex.qatools.allure.testng.AllureTestListener</value>
                    </property>
                </properties>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                    <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
                    <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

maven-surefire-plugin will invoke testng with `listener`

```
<properties>
   <property>
      <name>listener</name>
      <value>ru.yandex.qatools.allure.testng.AllureTestListener</value>
   </property>
</properties>
```

And pass aspectj settings as jvm argument:

```
- javaagent:${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/${aspectj.version}/aspectjweaver-${aspectj.version}.jar
```

Also you can refer to this [example project](https://github.com/allure-examples/allure-testng-example) for more clarity.